# Memory leak when shutting down embedded PySide/PyQt4 python code

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, qt4, pyside, address-sanitizer

I'm working on a C++ Qt4 application with an embedded python interpreter loading some PySide (or PyQt4) scripts. I noticed that Address Sanitizer was reporting a memory leak on exit c++ exit.

Trying to get to the bottom of this issue, I wrote a simple PySide code embedded in C++ to try to understand where the memory leak was coming from.

I poked around for quite some time trying various things, but to no avail. I suspect that it's linked to some ref-counting error causing some trouble when the Python interpreter shuts down, but I'm not sure.

Could somebody help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Python.h"

class EmbedPySide
{

public:

  EmbedPySide()
  {
    char name[] = "test";
    Py_SetProgramName(name);
    Py_Initialize();

    std::string code =
        "from PySide import QtGui\n"
        ""
        "class EmbededPySide(QtGui.QApplication):\n"
        ""
        "    def __init__(self):\n"
        "        super(EmbededPySide, self).__init__([])\n"
        "        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Shutdown')\n"
        "        self.button.clicked.connect(self.cleanUp)\n"
        "        self.win = QtGui.QMainWindow()\n"
        "        self.win.setCentralWidget(self.button)\n"
        "        self.win.move(600, 300)\n"
        "        self.win.show()\n"
        ""
        "    def cleanUp(self):\n"
        "        del self.button\n"
        "        del self.win\n"
        "        self.quit()\n"
        ""
        "if __name__=='__main__':\n"
        "    app = EmbededPySide()\n"
        "    app.exec_()";

    PyRun_SimpleString(code.c_str());
  }

  ~EmbedPySide()
  {
    Py_Finalize();
    std::cout << "Destructor called" << std::endl;
  }

};

int main()
{
  EmbedPySide embedded;

  std::cout << "Exiting" << std::endl;
}
```

And I compiled it with:

```
g++ main.cpp -O1 -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer \
-I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7
```

For clarity, here is the python code I wrote in the code string:

```
from PySide import QtGui

class EmbededPySide(QtGui.QApplication):

    def __init__(self):
        super(EmbededPySide, self).__init__([])
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Shutdown')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.cleanUp)
        self.win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
        self.win.setCentralWidget(self.button)
        self.win.move(600, 300)
        self.win.show()

    def cleanUp(self):
        del self.button
        del self.win
        self.quit()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = EmbededPySide()
    app.exec_()
```

On run, this is the output I get:

> Exiting
>
> Destructor called
>
> =================================================================
>   ==5063==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks
>
> Direct leak of 3377664 byte(s) in 1228 object(s) allocated from:
>       #0 0x7f161d4fb79a in __interceptor_calloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.2+0x9879a)
>       #1 0x7f161d0349ab  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0+0x1619ab)
>
> Direct leak of 786432 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
>       #0 0x7f161d4fb79a in __interceptor_calloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.2+0x9879a)
>       #1 0x7f161d0349ab  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0+0x1619ab)
>       #2 0x4f622d95dcb87ff  ()
>
> Direct leak of 24680 byte(s) in 27 object(s) allocated from:
>       #0 0x7f161d4fb602 in malloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.2+0x98602)
>       #1 0x7f161cfacd48 in _PyObject_GC_Malloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0+0xd9d48)
>
> [...]

Thank you!

Comment: Can you run with `export ASAN_OPTIONS=malloc_context_size=20` and install Python dbgsym package (for symbolized stacktrace)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the use of the -dbgsym packages, but if I understood properly, they are found automatically by the system if installed? I ran my program again with export ASAN_OPTIONS[..] enable. The full LeakSanitizer output can be found here: https://pastebin.ca/4007920

Comment: "they are found automatically by the system if installed" - yes, modulo [bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/binutils/+bug/1759248). You might also need to enable Asan address symbolizer as described e.g. [here](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerCallStack).

Comment: It took me some time to be able to get the python debug symbols, but here is the output of my second try: https://pastebin.com/SK6qCskP